# How to retake the throne?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

- I am the duke and got the claim on my Lieges kingdom.
- My liege can
  get 10000 troops (including vassals).
- I can get myself 10000 I have
  few other dukes (that are also vassals of my liege) allied to me.
- Currently, my faction has no any supporters.
- Also, I can create an alliance with 2 neighbouring countries, each has 2000-5000 army...

What is the best way for me to take over the kingdom?

Straightforward way is to demand installation of Claimant. In this case, I most likely won't be supported by my allies as they are first vassals... Am I right? Also, fighting the same size opponent is sketchy: both sides will lose too much. Though, I can bring allies... but that going to be a liability going forward.

I guess I better keep making schemas, spy on all potential supporters and boost the faction. It may take few years, but this looks more reliable.

I could also declare Independance, but later I would need to claim the throne anyway... so this does not look like a viable option at all.

Is there any other option? Please advise!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would most likely brute-force my way to the throne. Build up my retinues, make alliances, build a war chest and hire a ton of mercenaries.

If you'd like to play the long game, you have a couple of options:

- Marry your heir to one of your liege's daughters. That should allow your grandchild to gain a claim to the throne. If you manage to end up playing as that character, it should be a relatively painless way of getting a claim. Then you can press the claim, create a faction or murder your way to the crown.
- Another way would be to get on your liege's council, gain a favor with your liege and push for a succession law change vote and change the law to elective. Gain enough favor with all the other vassals and get voted to be king.
- Lastly, you can fabricate a claim and create a faction to press it (I assume you're already doing this but you don't mention who's the claimant of your faction).

As for the battle ahead, I'd suggest to wait for your liege to get out of a bloody war, keep an eye out on your liege profile window to see how their army is doing.

Comment: Thanks!
My main concern regarding going with faction was that I did not want to have a bloody war. Apparently, one duke joined my faction and together we had 125% of the army of the king... so he just gave up :)

Comment: @Budda That's lucky! I find the AI usually too "stubborn" to accept factions, even with overwhelmingly bad odds of winning.